# 'if' o 'switch' anidados, ¿cuál escoger?

Tags: javascript, buenas-prácticas

¿Se puede mejorar este código de if anidados?.

El código funciona, pero es dificil de leer. Había pensado que quizás podría mejorar con 'switch'

¿Se pueden usar 'switch' anidados?

El código que sigue pertenece al clásico juego "buscaminas".
[puedes probarlo aquí: buscaminas.eu](http://buscaminas.eu/)

Dicho código recorre todas las casillas de una cuadrícula para comprobar si las de alrededor contienen bombas y marcar esa cuadrícula con dicho número

Primero comprueba si las cuadrículas de alredor existen. En caso afirmativo comprueba si contienen bomba (letra "B"). Si es así, suman 1 a la variable 'nearBombs' y finalmente se asigna el valor de 'nearBombs' a la casilla que se esta recorriendo en el bucle.

Este es el código:

```
//bucle que recorre las celdas de la cuadrícula
for (let x = 0; x < numberOfRows; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < numberOfColumns; y++) {

            //inicializamos el contador a 0
            let nearBombs = 0;          

            //se comprueeba que la casilla esta vacia  
            if (bombBoard[x][y] ==" "){ 
                console.log('----------------------------');
                console.log ('x,y ='+ x +' '+y);

                //si esta vacia, 
                //se comprueba si existe una fila por encima de la
                // casilla que se esta evaluando
                if (x-1>=0){

                    //si existe, se comprueba si existe una columna 
                    //a su izquierda
                    if (y-1>=0){

                        //finalmente, si todo se confirma se comprueba 
                        //si tiene una bomba la casilla situada a su izquierda 
                        //y por encima y en caso afirmativo se suma una al contador    
                        if (bombBoard[x-1][y-1] =="B"){
                            console.log ('x-1,y-1 = es bomba'); 
                            nearBombs += 1;
                        } 
                    }

                    //se repite el procedimiento para la casila 
                    //que esta por encima pero situada en su misma columna      
                    if (bombBoard[x-1][y] =="B"){
                        console.log ('x-1,y = es bomba');   
                        nearBombs += 1;             
                    }

                    //se repite el procedimiento para la casila que esta
                    // encima y a la derecha
                    if (y+1<numberOfColumns){
                        if (bombBoard[x-1][y+1] =="B"){
                            console.log ('x-1,y+1 = es bomba'); 
                            nearBombs += 1;
                        } 
                    }

                } 

                //en este caso se comprueban las casillas que estan 
                //en la misma fila a derecha e izquierda 
                //(no es necesario comprobar si existe la fila) 
                if (y-1>=0){
                    console.log ('y-1-xxxxxx');
                    if (bombBoard[x][y-1] =="B"){
                        console.log ('x,y-1 = es bomba');   
                        nearBombs += 1;
                    } 
                }

                if (y+1<numberOfColumns){
                        console.log ('y+1 xxxxxxxxx');
                        if (bombBoard[x][y+1] =="B"){
                            console.log ('x,y+1 = es bomba');   
                            nearBombs += 1;
                        } 
                }

                //finalmente comprobamos si existe la fila inferior 
                //y repetimos el procediemiento para 
                //la columna a su izquierda, central y derecha
                if (x+1<numberOfRows){
                    console.log('x+1 ----');
                    if (y-1>=0){
                        console.log ('y-1 xxxxxxxxxx')
                        if (bombBoard[x+1][y-1] =="B"){
                            console.log ('x+1,y-1 = es bomba'); 
                            nearBombs += 1;
                        } 
                    }
                    if (bombBoard[x+1][y] =="B"){
                        console.log ('x+1,y = es bomba');   
                        nearBombs += 1;             
                    } 

                    if(y+1<numberOfColumns){
                        if (bombBoard[x+1][y+1] =="B"){
                            console.log ('x+1,y+1 = es bomba'); 
                            nearBombs += 1;
                        } 
                    }
                }

                console.log ("nearBombs =" + nearBombs);
                bombBoard[x][y] = nearBombs;
            }
        }

    }   
    return bombBoard;
```

He reordenado el código. Creo que mejora su legibilidad, pero siguen siendo con if consecutivos.

```
let nearBombs=0
for (let x = 0; x < numberOfRows; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < numberOfColumns; y++) {
        if (bombBoard[x][y] ==" "){
            nearBombs = 0;
            console.log('----------------------------');
            console.log ('x,y ='+ x +' '+y);
            if(x-1>=0 && y-1>=0 && bombBoard[x-1][y-1] =="B"){
                    nearBombs += 1; 
                    console.log ('superior izquierda');     
            } 

            if(x-1>=0 && bombBoard[x-1][y] =="B"){
                    console.log ('superior-centro');
                    nearBombs += 1; 
            }   

            if(x-1>=0 && y+1<numberOfColumns && bombBoard[x-1][y+1] =="B"){
                    console.log ('superior-derecha');
                    nearBombs += 1; 
            }   

            if(x+1<numberOfRows && y-1>=0 && bombBoard[x+1][y-1] =="B"){
                    console.log ('inferior-izquierda');
                    nearBombs += 1; 
            }

            if(x+1<numberOfRows && bombBoard[x+1][y] =="B"){
                    console.log ('inferior-centro');
                    nearBombs += 1; 
            }

            if(x+1<numberOfRows && y+1<numberOfColumns && bombBoard[x+1][y+1] =="B"){
                    console.log ('inferior-derecha');
                    nearBombs += 1;
            }

            if(y-1>=0 && bombBoard[x][y-1] =="B"){
                    console.log ('mima fila-izquierda');
                    nearBombs += 1; 
            }

            if(y+1<numberOfColumns && bombBoard[x][y+1] =="B"){
                    console.log ('misma fila-derecha');
                    nearBombs += 1; 
            }   
            bombBoard[x][y] = nearBombs;                
        }
    }
}
return bombBoard;
```

Comment: Esta pregunta tal y como la planteas puede dar lugar a opiniones. Para mi, ante la duda, y la tienes por un tema de legibilidad, escoge la *legibilidad siempre*. Si tienes decantarte por el rendimiento, hay herramientas para medirlo, si la diferencia no es apreciable: elige legibilidad.

Answer (score 0):

en la pagina  [MDN WEB DOCS- SWITCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), expone como:

**Reescribir multiples IF con SWITCH** y muestra este código.

```
var a = 100;
var b = NaN;
switch (true) {
  case isNaN(a) || isNaN(b):
    console.log('NaNNaN');
    break;
  case a === b:
    console.log(0);
    break;
  case a < b:
    console.log(-1);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(1);
}
```

El caso es que el canvio de **if** por **switch**, sobretodo después de la reescritura del código en If ordenandos (ver segundo código) no acorta el tamaño del código, ni creo que mejore su legibilidad.

Así que he optado por cambiar de estrategia.

Se utiliz el método maps, para rastrear todas las casillas en busca de las casillas que continen una B y una vez localizada, se comprueba que las que le rodean no contienen una "B" y en tal caso se les añade +1.

El código es este:

```
    const newBombBoard = bombBoard.map((row, numDeFila) => {
        row.map((cel,posCell) =>{
            if(cel == "B"){
                for (let x=-1;x<=1;x++){
                    if(numDeFila+x >=0 && numDeFila+x < numberOfRows){
                        for (let y=-1;y<=1;y++) {
                            if(posCell+y >= 0 && posCell+ y <numberOfColumns && bombBoard[numDeFila+x][posCell+y] != 'B'){
                                bombBoard[numDeFila+x][posCell+y] = (parseInt(bombBoard[numDeFila+x][posCell+y]) || 0)+1;
                            }

                        }               
                    }

                }

            }   
        });         
    });
    return bombBoard;
```

Quizàs no sea más legible, pero es mas claramente más conciso.